# how to set the size of Corebluetooth notification from peripheral

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

My ObjC corebluetooth central, on my iPhone iOS, receives a "stream" of notifications* from my virtual BLE peripheral running on iPad.  But each notification is only 16 bytes.

-* Not a byte stream, but a "stream" of continuous, contiguous notification sets of bytes, where each set (ie. a packet) contains a single notification.

How can I increase each BLE notification size?
Greater size would reduce my backend processing at central.

Comment: It is up to the peripheral how much data it sends.  BLE characteristics are not a stream; They have specific number of bytes.  The maximum transmission size of a BLE characteristic is fairly limited; About 30-60 bytes.  If you truly have a stream and can modify the peripheral, you could use an [`L2Cap` channel](https://github.com/paulw11/L2Cap)

Comment: Not a byte stream, but a "stream" of continuous, contiguous notification sets of bytes, where each set (ie. a packet) contains a single notification

Answer (score 1):

As Paulw11 mentioned, the peripheral decides how much data it sends. However, if your objective is to reduce the backend processing at central by increasing the throughput, then you have several ways to achieve this, namely: decreasing the **Connection Interval**, increasing the **ATT_MTU**, using **Data Length Extension**, and (if both devices support BT5 features) using **2MPHY Modulation**. The links below have more information on this:-

- [Maximising BLE Throughput: Everything You Need to Know](https://punchthrough.com/ble-throughput-part-4/)
- [A Practical Guide to BLE Throughput](https://interrupt.memfault.com/blog/ble-throughput-primer)
- [BLE 5.0 Max Byte Size](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/665058)